# How to set listview border in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I've tried digging through the JavaFX CSS reference and googling but have been unsuccessful in figuring out how to remove the border on a listview in JavaFX.

I've tried setting the border and stroke widths to 0px. I've tried setting the border/stroke colors to transparent. No matter what I do, there is what looks to be a 1px solid black border around the listview.

Any ideas on how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

```
list.setStyle("-fx-background-insets: 0 ;");
```

Comment: Most FX Controls set borders by having two different background colors with different insets. The default settings for ListView are `-fx-background-color: -fx-box-border, -fx-control-inner-background ;` and `-fx-background-insets: 0,1 ;`. The resulting effect is a background color of `-fx-control-inner-background` and a one pixel border (since the difference in insets is 1px) with color `-fx-box-border`.